# Run script agains all computer in Active Directory AD Powershell

Tags: powershell

I would like ask you how I can run my PowerShell script against all computers in AD. I tried set all computers names into variable and then run script foreach but I cannot figure out computer name from variable into my script.

Thank you for your help

````
$HostName  =  @{n="Hostname";e={[System.Net.Dns]::GetHostName()}}
# IP
$IP  =  @{n="IP";e={gwmi Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration -filter 'IPEnabled=True'|select -expandproperty IPAddress|Where {$_ -notmatch ':'}}}
#MAC
$MAC  =  @{n="MAC";e={get-wmiobject -class "Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration" |Where{$_.IpEnabled -Match "True"} |select MACAddress}}
#OS
$OS  =  @{n="OS";e={(Get-WMIObject win32_operatingsystem).name}}
#UserLogin
$UserProperty = @{n="user";e={(New-Object System.Security.Principal.SecurityIdentifier $_.ReplacementStrings[1]).Translate([System.Security.Principal.NTAccount])}}
#Log ON / Log OFF
$TypeProperty = @{n="Action";e={if($_.EventID -eq 7001) {"Logon"} else {"Logoff"}}}
#TIME
$TimeProeprty = @{n="Time";e={$_.TimeGenerated}}
#SELECT 
Get-EventLog System -Source Microsoft-Windows-Winlogon| Where { $_.TimeGenerated -GT (Get-Date).AddDays(-30) } | select $UserProperty,$TypeProperty,$TimeProeprty,$HostName,$IP,$MAC,$OS    ```
````

Comment: You could use group policy the run it on all the computers or use Invoke-Command. The system name is held in the environment variable $Env:COMPUTERNAME

Comment: @I.T Delinquent Its not work $Computers = (Get-ADComputer -filter *).Name
Invoke-Command -ComputerName $computers {

Answer (score 0):

Add the DNSHostName property from AD to the object?

```
$Computers = Get-ADComputer -Filter * -properties DNSHostName
$HostName  =  @{n="Hostname";e={$computers.DNSHostName}}
```